# are there reasons for sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.setWakeupSocket0 to hang

Tags: java, sockets, nio, freeze, wakeup

With JDK 1.6.024, we see threads consuming near 100% CPU in `setWakeupSocket0()` for a socket connection. This native method is called from `setWakeupSocket()` which in turn is the private part of `wakeup()` in this particular `SelectorImpl`. What could cause this method to get stuck for minutes?

Update Feb, 2019: We also see prolonged execution times with late versions JDK 1.8.